# Flexbox item is shrunk down on iOS 9 when the parent container is set as a specific height

Tags: css, flexbox, ios9, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have encountered this bug on iOS version 9 when using with latest Boostrap 4 Beta. Basically I have a parent div and an ul element that contains multiple list items. The parent div is a flexbox with the dimensions are set to some numbers and turn on overflow for the children element. The list item is supposed to take 100% of the height of the parent. Here is the link to the demo code: https://codepen.io/nguyenthai/pen/jawzRo.

Most browsers display that fine. However, only on any version of iOS 9, the list is shrunk down since Safari does not calculate the proper height for the container. I believe there are several variants of this bug existed and most of them have been fixed from iOS 10 and above. But I do need the support for iOS 9 and so far none of the workarounds that I have found is working properly. Setting `flex-shrink: 0;` or using `flex: 1 0 auto;` did not yield success result. The only thing that would somehow mitigate this is to switch the list to use `display: block` rather than flex. However, that could have effect on other browsers as well and I only want the fix to apply specifically for any iOS version 9.

So any ideas on how to fix this without radically changing the syntax and affecting other browsers?

Comment: Have you tried doing the exact same using plain Flexbox properties? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPzmNL

Comment: The problem is that because of Bootstrap, I do not want to modify their default behavior and use entirely similar thing where I can just apply Bootstrap style and fix it by somehow replicate the same effect from the fiddle. I just checked the code and that apparently fixed in iOS 9. So if I can figure out how to incorporate that with BS with minimal change to the underlying framework, that would be perfect.

Comment: If that code worked, it is interesting. The major difference is it use `flex-shrink: 0` on the `li`. So then I need to ask, how did you test `flex-shrink: 0`? ... I also undeleted my initial answer, and wonder, does that work on your iOS9+

Comment: I was testing it with the container and not individual item list. I thought that the container was shrinking and therefore squishing the list down to fit entire list in the same height. Edit: Putting that property in the list item definitely fixes the issue.

Comment: Yup. Thanks you very much.

Comment: Great...and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A flex item by default is allowed to shrink, `flex-shrink: 1`, and it appears this is also what iOS9 allow them to.

By giving the `li` `flex-shrink: 0` should prevent that.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pdwOYN)

Stack snippet

```css
.test {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.list-group-item {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="test d-flex flex-column">
  <ul class="list-group h-100">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
<div>
```